# How to display video from the buffer data getting from nodejs server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, webrtc

This is the buffer data I am getting on my server side from my live webcam using `webRtc` and `socket.io`

```
[ <Buffer 1a 45 df a3 9f 42 86 81 01 42 f7 81 01 42 f2 81 04 42 f3 81 08 42 82 84 77 65 62 6d 42 87 81 04 42 85 81 02 18 53 80 67 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 15 49 ... 53876 more bytes> ]
[ <Buffer 1a 45 df a3 9f 42 86 81 01 42 f7 81 01 42 f2 81 04 42 f3 81 08 42 82 84 77 65 62 6d 42 87 81 04 42 85 81 02 18 53 80 67 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 15 49 ... 53876 more bytes>,
  <Buffer 41 ab 81 03 c0 80 fb 83 84 97 85 2d c7 d9 a6 12 c0 c8 c0 a4 bf bb 8b 6b 94 f1 78 40 a5 e3 29 e1 42 de f0 9a 4d 94 bd 3c c8 ae 9c 07 b2 c2 65 e1 22 ea ... 196152 more bytes> ]
```

Now I just want to send that data to my HTML page and play the webcam video.

I am using angular4 and my code is not working, my code is

```
  video: HTMLVideoElement;

  constructor(private _chatService: ChatService) {

    this.video = document.querySelector('video');
    const myMediaSource = new MediaSource();
     this.video.src = URL.createObjectURL(myMediaSource);

    const videoSourceBuffer = myMediaSource
      .addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001e"');

    this._chatService.recieveData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // image is shown below
        videoSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
      });

  }
```

But it is giving an error of

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to the parameter of type
>   'BufferSource'.

When I am trying to console data, I am getting data in my front-end as

[image]

Someone, please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a node module called NodeMediaServer which might work. This is how you would do it with rtmp:

```
const { NodeMediaServer } = require("node-media-server");

const config = {
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 60,
    ping_timeout: 30
  },
  http: {
    port: 8000,
    allow_origin: "*"
  }
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config);
nms.run();
```

And this is what you would use on the frontend to pick it up and play it with flv:

```
buildPlayer() {
    if (this.player || !this.props.stream) {
      return;
    }
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.player = flv.createPlayer({
      type: "flv",
      url: `http://localhost:8000/live/${id}.flv`
    });
    this.player.attachMediaElement(this.videoRef.current);
    this.player.load();
  }
```

Not sure if it helps but worth a try.